# Is there an equivalent of "Insecure origins treated as secure" of Chrome flag in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, secure-context

I am using "`Insecure origins treated as secure`" flag in Chrome for development purposes and I have added some websites like `http://myWebsite:port`. It works great in Chrome. Now I need the same feature in Firefox but cannot find it. Is it possible to do so in Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, not yet, but there's an open bug about adding one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410365

Answer (score -1):

Please do the following steps to trust the insecure URL in Firefox,

1. Load the URL with HTTPS eg: https://test-abc.com
2. You will be getting a black screen with "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead", click "Advanced.." button
3. A new content will be loaded on the same page with "Accept the Risk and Continue" button, click the button
4. refresh the page, now it will start working like chrome "Insecure origins treated as secure"

Comment: This isn't equivalent to Chrome's 'insecure origins treated as secure.' This is the equivalent to the Chrome trick of typing 'thisisunsafe' when getting the Potential Security Risk Ahead screen.

Comment: That would only work if it's an HTTPS server